# iOS7 Xcode utility app - UINavigationBar on Flipsideviewcontroller not spaced properly?

Tags: xcode, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have this issue, where as standard the flipsideviewcontroller UINavigationBar looks like this:

[image: Weird Layout]

Anybody have any ideas on how to move the UINavigationBar either down, or to stop the ugliness of it all?

Comment: I don't know if its just me, but the image is not displaying.

Comment: Sorry - Image now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky. :) You need to set a delegate for the UINavigationBar - this will probably be the FlipsideViewController. You can do this in the storyboard, or in code - for example, if you have an outlet to the navigation bar:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationBar.delegate = self;
}
```

Now comes the important part: implement in the delegate this method:

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar {
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

With auto layout, it is also crucial that the top of the navigation bar have a zero-constant constraint to the Top Layout Guide. This is not entirely easy to set up because there is a bug in Xcode that will try to turn this into a bad constraint from the *bottom* of the navigation bar. If that happens:

- Delete the top constraint.
- Move the nav bar down the screen.
- Control-drag to form the top constraint to the Top Layout Guide again.
- Now select the top constraint and manually set its Constant to 0, to make the nav bar move back up again.

Comment: Tried that just now and no improvement at all. This is really weird as it never behaved like this when building against iOS 6 apps.

Comment: @LyconalBest As I said, it's tricky. Any of the steps I outlined can go wrong, and then it won't work. But it can be done. Put the project up on github and I'll try to fix it for you.